# How to check if a variable is declared in JavaScript?

Tags: variables, declaration

If I declare variable like this,

```
let variable;
```

How to check if the variable is declared?

(If it is **initilized**, I will do this way..)

```
if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch ReferenceError to check if the variable is declared or not.

```
var declared = true;
try{
    theVariable;
}
catch(e) {
    if(e.name == "ReferenceError") {
        declared = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `declared = false;` in the catch.

Comment: Also, last line, ) should be }. minor, but key.

Answer (score 1):

A variable that is not declared will produce a ReferenceError, so you need a simple try catch:

```
try {
  if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') { }
} catch(error) {
  //Handle nondeclared
}
```